# Show that T(n)=4×T(n−1)−T(n−2)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

T(n) is the number of spanning trees for a n-ladder.

Show that $ T(n)=4×T(n−1)−T(n−2) $

As a proof, I don't really know how to solve this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I tried to first solve for a 3 case, and drew out the ladder as such:

[image]

as $ T_n+1=3*T_n $, but I kinda dont know where to go from here.

Comment: It would help to be more specific about the problem.  What is $T$?

Comment: Sorry, editing the question with more information

Comment: Have you tried proving by induction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start. The fourth way is to add on three blue lines shown in my diagram:

[image]

Obviously this creates a cycle, so delete the edge that I have crossed through with two blue lines.

This method can only be used if in fact the top edge is already part of a spanning tree. The number of spanning trees that include this edge is $T(n-1)-T(n-2)$.

Comment: This helps, thank you